# Is there a base such that the fermat test is always correct?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, primality-test

The Fermat primality test base $a$ says $N$ is probably prime if $a^{N-1}=1\mod N$. $N$ is a pseudoprime base $a$ if it is probably prime, but not prime.

Does there exist a base $a$ such that the only pseudoprimes base $a$ are Carmichael numbers?

More generally, could we find $k$ bases such that if $N$ is a pseudoprime to all of these bases, then $N$ is a Carmichael number?

To solve this I think we're gonna construct a pseudoprime base $a$ then show its not a Carmichael number by the classification theorem. Cant find any reference for this.

Comment: I think , for every positive integer $n$ , there exists a semiprime being a strong fermat pseudoprime to the bases upto $n$. This would show that the answer is "no".

Comment: For the semiprime $$n:=790489610041255741$$ , the smallest base $b$ for which $$b^{n-1}\ne 1\mod n$$ holds is $b=83$.

Comment: For $$13358375967393860493263578021$$ , the smallest base is $109$